# To find edges sum of a Maximum Spanning Tree for a complete graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

You are given a array and indices of array represents nodes of a graph, given the graph is complete i.e. all indices are connected to each other. You are also told edge weight is equal to absolute difference of value present at two connecting indexes, now we are interested to span a maximum spanning tree and output sum of edges weight of that maximum spanning tree.

I already know that is so obvious question we can apply Prim or Kruskal's algorithm to find it out efficiently but the problem is we can have 1e5 nodes so to store all of them ( 1e10 results ) and then evaluate will be complex and time consuming.

So I wonder do we have some efficient shortcut for complete graph to find sum of edges weight of a maximum spanning tree?